# XML to Java object with recursive child definition

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb

How can I convert this XML to Java objects?

```
 <template>
        <condition name="A">
            <li value="A">
                <condition name="B">
                    <li value="BB">Value B</li>
                    <li value="BBB">Value BBB</li>
                </condition>
            </li>
            <li>
                <condition name="C">
                    <li value="CC">Value CC</li>
                    <li value="CCC">Value CCC</li>
                    <li>
                        <condition name="D">
                            <li value="DD">Value DD</li>
                            <li value="DDD">Value DDD</li>
                         </condition>
                    </li>
                </condition>
            </li>
        </condition>
    </template>
```

`Condition` must have `Li` tag and `li` tag might have another `condition` and that `condition` will have `li` that might have another `condition` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to model the XML elements by corresponding Java classes with some `@Xml...` annotations.
This is fairly straight-forward.
The fact that there is recursion involved does not raise any additional problems.

A class modeling the `<template>` root element (with nested `<condition>` element):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "template")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Template {

    @XmlElement(name = "condition")
    private Condition condition;

    // getters and setters
}
```

A class modeling the `<condition>` element (with nested `<li>` elements):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Condition {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "li")
    private List<ListItem> listItems;

    // getters and setters
}
```

A class modeling the `<li>` element (with nested `<condition>` element):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ListItem {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "value")
    private String value;

    @XmlElement(name = "condition")
    private Condition condition;

    // getters and setters
}
```

You can test all these classes with a conversion XML -> Java -> XML like this:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Template.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
Template template = (Template) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("template.xml"));
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(template, System.out);
```

Comment: `ListItem` can contains not only attribute `value` with `condition`, but also tag value (string). How to get tag value, like `Value DD` from example?

Comment: I got `ListItem` text value via `@XmlMixed List<String> values;` https://metamug.com/article/xml/jaxb-unmarshalling-for-type-mixed-content.html

Answer (score 0):

JAXB,

First of all you will need to create a model class following your XML and then use JAXB to convert to java obj

Comment: Yes, how can I create of model with that type of scenario..

Comment: i think you will need to create more getters and setters for each "name" and "value" and then other for the value inside

Comment: but it can be infinite.. there might be condition inside li